# is there any formula that describes the frequency distribution of numbers(from 1 to N) across all partitions of N?

Tags: integer-partitions

I was interested in frequency of numbers across all partitions of a particular number N.

say 5 = 5, 4+1, 3+2, 3+1+1, 2+2+1, 2+1+1+1, 1+1+1+1+1

frequencies of 1 to 5 are 11,3,2,1,1 respectively.

is there any formula describing their frequency distribution?

the plot of such a frequency distribution for 50 and 70 are

[frequency of numbers across all partitions of 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wrPW.jpg)

[frequency of numbers across all partitions of 70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHgpB.jpg)

Comment: Since for parts $m\gt N/2$ this is the number of partitions of $N-m$, there can't be a more closed form for this than for the partition function.

Comment: could you please elaborate? your explanation was not clear

Comment: Perhaps an example will help. You used $N=5$ as an example; then consider $m=3\gt5/2$: The frequency of $3$ is the number of partitions of $N-m=5-3=2$, since the partitions of $5$ with one part $3$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the partitions of $2$.